# How to add my apps connection in Phonebook/Contacts as Whatsapp and Viber does?

Tags: android, contacts, whatsapp, connection

[image]

I want my Android apps **connection** to be added in **contact**. I will check whether the user is using my app or not, based o the result I need to add connection in the **existing** contacts.

I have taken many reference but it adds a new contact with addition of a connection. One of the sample I have used is [here](https://github.com/nemezis/SampleContacts)

So can anyone tell me what is the procedure to add account in the existing contact?

I am able to **create account** which is visible in **Setting** menu of phone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also use this tutorial but one change that you have to make is in `addContact()`
In this tutorial, that you are preferring, you have to change the following code.

1. `addContact()` deletes all the contacts that has account type of your package, so you have to add more conditions of deleting that particular contact.
2. you have to add the details that has already added in existing contact in which you want to add your account that is contact number or email or name etc.

```
public static void addContact(Context context, MyContact contact) {
        ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
         // add condition that you want to check
        String where= RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = ? AND " +RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY+"=?";
        //values of that condotion
        String[] value=new String[] { AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE ,contact.name};
        resolver.delete(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, where, value);

        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, true))
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_NAME)
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE)
                //.withValue(RawContacts.SOURCE_ID, 12345)
                //.withValue(RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE, RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DISABLED)
                .build());

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(Settings.CONTENT_URI, true))
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_NAME)
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE)
                .withValue(Settings.UNGROUPED_VISIBLE, 1)
                .build());

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(Data.CONTENT_URI, true)) 
                .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0) 
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE) 
                .withValue(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, contact.name) 
                .withValue(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, contact.lastName) 
                .build()); 

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(Data.CONTENT_URI, true)) 
                .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0) 
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, "12342145")

                .build());


        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(Data.CONTENT_URI, true)) 
                 .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                 .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                 .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, "sample@email.com")
                 .build());     


        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(Data.CONTENT_URI, true))
                .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, MIMETYPE)
                .withValue(Data.DATA1, 12345)
                .withValue(Data.DATA2, "sample")
                .withValue(Data.DATA3, "sample")
                .build());
        try {
            ContentProviderResult[] results = resolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            i++;
            if (results.length == 0)
                ;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```